# Select additional fields when using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, jpa, ebean

I'm using MSSQL 2008 R2, and having an issue with the following situation:

With the following query, I will get data I expect (the `max` and `min` speed for each date).
The `CAST(m.date as DATE)` removes the time part of my `datetime`

```
SELECT CAST(d.date as DATE) as date,
       MAX(d.speed) AS maxSpeed,
       AVG(d.speed) AS avgSpeed
  FROM Driver as d
 WHERE d.date between '2014-01-01 09:00:00.491' and
       '2014-03-11 17:00:00.491'
 GROUP BY CAST(d.date as DATE)
 ORDER BY date DESC
```

My problem is, I want to select some other fields from `d` as well (like the userID, username, etc). If I modify the query to include the additional fields, like so:

```
SELECT CAST(d.date as DATE) as date,
       MAX(d.speed) AS maxSpeed,
       AVG(d.speed) AS avgSpeed,
       d.userId
  FROM Driver as d
 WHERE d.date between '2014-01-01 09:00:00.491' and
       '2014-03-11 17:00:00.491'
 GROUP BY CAST(d.date as DATE)
 ORDER BY date DESC
```

I get this error:

```
d.userId is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

So, I add `d.userId` to the `GROUP BY` clause, and my data changes, of course, and will now include multiple entries per date.

So, my question is how can I select additional fields, while still maintaining the original data I want (the `min` and `max` for each unique date)?

Comment: Which value of `userid` do you want on any given date?  Presumably, there is more than one.

Comment: This is a good point. I think I've been conceptualizing this incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select rows from `Driver` along with the `max()` and `avg()` values for `speed`, then use window functions:

```
SELECT d.*, CAST(d.date as DATE) as date,
       MAX(d.speed) OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(d.date as DATE)) AS maxSpeed,
       AVG(d.speed) OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(d.date as date)) AS avgSpeed
FROM Driver as d
WHERE d.date between '2014-01-01 09:00:00.491' and '2014-03-11 17:00:00.491'
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

EDIT:

If you want one row per driver, per day, then use a simple `group by`:

```
SELECT d.userId, CAST(d.date as DATE) as date,
       MAX(d.speed) as maxSpeed, AVG(d.speed) as avgSpeed
FROM Driver as d
WHERE d.date between '2014-01-01 09:00:00.491' and '2014-03-11 17:00:00.491'
GROUP BY d.userId, CAST(d.date as DATE) 
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

If you want to add additional columns, you need to add them both to the `select` and the `group by`.

Comment: This is VERY close to what I was imagining (and by the way I have never see the `OVER` or `PARTITION BY` keywords before, so that's for opening my eyes to them.

If I add `DISTINCT` after `SELECT`, I get basically what I was hoping for - one row for each driver, with their min/max speed for a single day.

I can get the rest of the way with programming language from here.

Thank you!

Comment: Note to mention that while this works just great in MsSql Studio, it will not work in `PlayFramework 2.2.2` with `Ebean`...  No fault of the query, which is a thing of beauty, but due to an error in Ebean that has been fixed as of `3.3.1-RC2`, which of course, is not compatible with Play 2.2.2.